# 2 Forms of Java Iterator

Tags: java, list, linked-list, iterator

I was trying to iterate through a list "ret" which is a list of lists of integers. That is, "ret" is of type `List<List<Integer>>`, so I used the following code:

```
for (ListIterator<List<Integer>> it1 = ret.listIterator<>(); it1.hasNext(); ) {
    List<Integer> list1 = it1.next();
}
```

However, the IDE gives me an error "illegal start of expression". So I tried the following form and it was correct:

```
for (ListIterator it1 = ret.listIterator(); it1.hasNext(); ) {
    List<Integer> list1 = (List<Integer>) it1.next();
}
```

I wonder why is this and what is the difference of these two forms?

Comment: is there a typo in 
   ret.listIterator<>();? 

those <> shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
for (ListIterator<List<Integer>> it1 = ret.listIterator<>(); it1.hasNext(); ) {
    List<Integer> list1 = it1.next();
}
```

to this:

```
for (ListIterator<List<Integer>> it1 = ret.listIterator(); it1.hasNext(); ) {
    List<Integer> list1 = it1.next();
}
```

and then you don't need explicit casting. The angle brackets are not used to call the function that returns the iterator, see the API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html

This code compiled and ran for me:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test{
public static void main(String[] a){

List<List<Integer>> ret = new ArrayList<>();

for (ListIterator<List<Integer>> it1 = ret.listIterator(); it1.hasNext(); ) {
    List<Integer> list1 = it1.next();
}

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html

"A ListIterator has no current element; its cursor position always lies between the element that would be returned by a call to previous() and the element that would be returned by a call to next()."

Quiet simply Iterators are not lists don't confuse them.